# Pointwise convergence of the series $f_n(x)=x^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I know that the sequence
$$
f_n(x) = x^n
$$
Converges pointwise to 
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & 0\leq x < 1 \\ 1 & x=1\end{cases}
$$
in $[0,1]$.

My question is - is it right to say that the sequence converges to the line $x = 1$ for $x\in(1,\infty)$?

Edit:
Confused with sequence not series

Comment: Yes I mixed another exercise I had, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If $x>1$, the sequence $x^n$ diverges.

The line $x=1$ is always going to be distance 1 away from the point $(2,2^n)$. So there's no uniformity.

Comment: I know that, but when graphing $x^n$ for $x>1$ as $n$ gets larger the graph gets more and more perpendicular to the $x$-axis. I know that it does not converge to any function, I asked about a curve

Comment: These kinda of convergence behaviors are usually measured with the hausdorf metric. I don't think it will converge in the hausdorf metric though.